# Possible to RDP into a desktop other than current one(using desktop manager)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, desktop, remote-access, virtual-desktop

I am using a Virtual Desktop Manager to run 4 desktops that I use. I am wondering if it is possible to RDP into a different desktop than the one that is currently being viewed on the local PC? So I am viewing a desktop that is currently hidden on the PC. I am running Windows 7 Home premium.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if it's possible to remote desktop from PC A to B and then remote desktop into C from B, the answer is **yes**, you can make remote desktop chains from computer to computer as much as you like, provided that you don't create a loop.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean desktop computers. I meant each computer has 4 desktops that I can switch through. Each desktop can have different applications on it.

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't switch desktops the way you normally do after remotting in?

Answer (score 0):

after remote desktop, open task manager, hit users, select the sessions and hit "connect to"